# Draw bar graph using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to draw a bar graph using the values returned from server using jQuery. I use the following code,

I try to draw graph using the values in the variable `data_list`, the issue is the graph draws first with empty values the I got values from server.

I am a newbie to Javascript and jQuery. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>the title</title>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">   
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var data_list
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $.get('/api/', function(data) {            
                data_list = data;
                alert(data_list); // alert work second

              });  

        });
        alert('test')  // first this alert work
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                      function drawChart() {

                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_list);
                        var options = {
                          title: 'Company Performance',
                          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                      }   

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
            <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
        </form>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts in yout JS code. The first is loading the chart data from your API with an AJAX request. The second starts the chart library and attach the data in this line:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_list);
```

The problem is the ajax request is asynchronous and the data is not loaded yet when you attach that data. The data_list var will be avaliable when the AJAX request finishes and not when the page is loaded. In other words, you must separated the initialization of the chart and the data attach to it, or simply: init the graph, load the data and set it to the chart when the AJAX request is done. A simple example with your code (not tested) could be:

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.get('/api/', function(data) {            
              data_list = data;
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_list);
              var options = {
                  title: 'Company Performance',
                  hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
              };

              var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
         });
     });  
 }
```

Remember this code is not tested, it ilustrates the idea of the correct initialization:
- Load Google Chart Library
- Load the data
- When the data is loaded, init the concrete chart

The asynchronous load adds some complexity to the code, but are the base of programming in JavaScript with AJAX and DOM events. Another option, more readable and simple, is to use jquery deferred objects and promises. More on deferred and promises:
- http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=es